# for Loop repeating itself once, even when told not to

Tags: java, android, loops, android-studio, datastore

I can't for the life of me figure out why this string comparison loop will loop again after even when finding that no values in the array = that value.

```
        Query p = new Query(section).addSort("Login", Query.SortDirection.DESCENDING) ;
    PreparedQuery qp = datastore.prepare(p);

    int listSize = 0;
    for(Entity amount : qp.asIterable()){
        listSize++;
    }

    for (Entity result2 : qp.asIterable()) {
        if (breakOff==true) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("1stloop size is " + size + result2.getProperty("Login"));
            MyBean temp2 = new MyBean();
            temp2.setData((String) result2.getProperty("Login"));

            Query q = new Query("sent").addSort("Login", Query.SortDirection.DESCENDING);
            PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);

            int i = 0;
            for (Entity result : pq.asIterable()) {

                i++;
                System.out.println("2ndloop is "+ result.getProperty("Login"));
                MyBean temp = new MyBean();
                temp.setData((String) result.getProperty("Login"));

                if (temp.getData().equals(temp2.getData())) {
                    System.out.println("broken");
                    break;
                } else if (i >= size) {


                    sentNum.setData(temp2.getData());
                    Entity logins = new Entity("sent");
                    logins.setProperty("Login", temp2.getData());
                    datastore.put(logins);
                    System.out.println("sizematch wrote " + temp2.getData());
                    breakOff = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("increase" + i);

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I call a breakOff==true so the loop wouldn't go through it again, but it always does. Once exactly.

Comment: Since this is only a small snippet of your code I don't think there really is enough information to go off of here in trying to solve the issue that you are having.

Comment: Well, have you used a debugger to see if `breakOff = true;` is hit on the first iteration of the loop. Based on what you are saying, it is quite clear that it is getting hit on the second iteration. Use a debugger, and fix your conditionals.

Comment: How do I go line by line on the debugger? All I see is breakOff = true.

Answer (score 0):

Well, look at the place you check if you need to break, it is in the start of the loop. That means that the program will break in the next enter to the loop, so it will run one more time exactly.
To fix it, just change the statement location to the end of the second loop.
here is your fixed code: (by the way it is a mess, try to organize it a bit)

```
  Query p = new Query(section).addSort("Login", Query.SortDirection.DESCENDING) ;
    PreparedQuery qp = datastore.prepare(p);

    int listSize = 0;
    for(Entity amount : qp.asIterable()){
        listSize++;
    }

    for (Entity result2 : qp.asIterable()) {

            System.out.println("1stloop size is " + size + result2.getProperty("Login"));
            MyBean temp2 = new MyBean();
            temp2.setData((String) result2.getProperty("Login"));

            Query q = new Query("sent").addSort("Login", Query.SortDirection.DESCENDING);
            PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);

            int i = 0;
            for (Entity result : pq.asIterable()) {

                i++;
                System.out.println("2ndloop is "+ result.getProperty("Login"));
                MyBean temp = new MyBean();
                temp.setData((String) result.getProperty("Login"));

                if (temp.getData().equals(temp2.getData())) {
                    System.out.println("broken");
                    break;
                } else if (i >= size) {


                    sentNum.setData(temp2.getData());
                    Entity logins = new Entity("sent");
                    logins.setProperty("Login", temp2.getData());
                    datastore.put(logins);
                    System.out.println("sizematch wrote " + temp2.getData());
                    breakOff = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("increase" + i);

                }

            }

              if (breakOff)
                      break;
    }
```

notice that there is no reason to check `if(breakOff==true)` as you can also check `if(breakOff)` and get the same answer. The reason is that `breakOff==true` will give you true if and only if `breakOff` is true, but `if(breakOff)` will be true if and only if `breakOff` is true, so they are same.

Comment: Your code is running, and the program is reading the break. Unfortunately it  still iterates through the code once.

Comment: when you say it still run another time, do you mean the inner loop or the outer loop?

Comment: The outer loop. If I

if (breakOff) {
                System.out.println("brokenOFF");
                break;
}

it would give me two sets of "brokenOFF"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. I think you see the inner loop that continue to running as no one told the inner loop to stop and think it is the outer loop. try to add `break;` just after `breakOff=true;` (see my edited fixed answer) and tell me if there is still a problem.

Comment: Using your method, doesn't seem to work.
I set PrintLn methods to both outer and inner classes, therefore I'm pretty sure the outside loop is still getting called, since messages are showing up.Yet, the loop just won't break, but will break the second iteration. How???

Comment: did you try to debug it and see exactly what happens? Toggle a break point when the `breakOff = true;` and see what happens then, step by step.

Comment: I have the debug window open, and I'm seeing a bunch of stuff. What exactly are the important things to look out for?

Comment: make the debug run until get to the line `breakOff=true`, and then go line by line and check if he really is enter the loop once again. if he is, you will see it and maybe you will understand how to fix it. if not - then the problem is somewhere else. Anyway, follow the variables tab, I don't think that you need the other tabs.

Comment: according to this,after first iteration it loops through to the top of the class, while maintaining it's value. Does the table of variables mean what is being done after the break toggle is called?

Comment: the table of var show you the what is inside each of your vars in this moment.

Comment: How do I go line by line on the debugger? All I see is breakOff = true.